# after update node js 'node-gyp' module not install with npm

Tags: node.js, canvas, npm, centos7

When I update Node js in my Linux machine (CentOS by nvm) the modules that have `node-gyp` and `node-pre-gyp` are disabled and need to be reinstalled, For example `canvas`, `ursa`, ...

i tested this solution:

I think delete this directory and clean the cache of `npm`  is better:

```
rm -rf ~/.node-gyp/
rm -r node_modules/.bin/;
rm -r build/
npm cache clean
```

and test

```
npm uninstall node-gyp
npm install -g node-gyp
```

and

```
npm uninstall node-pre-gyp
npm install -g node-pre-gyp
```

finally:

```
npm install <your module>
```

But these two modules go wrong and the installation process is over from `package.json`. what can i do with this errors?

```
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (/root/.nvm/v10.16.3/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:345:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:198:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:248:12)
gyp ERR! System Linux 3.10.0-957.21.2.el7.x86_64
gyp ERR! command "/root/.nvm/v10.16.3/bin/node" "/root/.nvm/v10.16.3/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "configure" "--fallback-to-build" "--module=/root/node_modules/canvas/build/Release/canvas.node" "--module_name=canvas" "--module_path=/root/node_modules/canvas/build/Release" "--napi_version=4" "--node_abi_napi=napi" "--napi_build_version=0" "--node_napi_label=node-v64" "--python=python2.7"
gyp ERR! cwd /root/node_modules/canvas
gyp ERR! node -v v10.16.3
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok 
node-pre-gyp ERR! build error 
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute '/root/.nvm/v10.16.3/bin/node /root/.nvm/v10.16.3/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --module=/root/node_modules/canvas/build/Release/canvas.node --module_name=canvas --module_path=/root/node_modules/canvas/build/Release --napi_version=4 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v64 --python=python2.7' (1)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/root/node_modules/canvas/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/compile.js:83:29)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:198:13)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:982:16)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:259:5)
node-pre-gyp ERR! System Linux 3.10.0-957.21.2.el7.x86_64
node-pre-gyp ERR! command "/root/.nvm/v10.16.3/bin/node" "/root/node_modules/canvas/node_modules/.bin/node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build"
node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd /root/node_modules/canvas
node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v10.16.3
node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.11.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok 
Failed to execute '/root/.nvm/v10.16.3/bin/node /root/.nvm/v10.16.3/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --module=/root/node_modules/canvas/build/Release/canvas.node --module_name=canvas --module_path=/root/node_modules/canvas/build/Release --napi_version=4 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v64 --python=python2.7' (1)
npm WARN PartServer@6.2.0 No description
npm WARN PartServer@6.2.0 license should be a valid SPDX license expression

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! canvas@2.6.0 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the canvas@2.6.0 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2019-09-17T07_45_58_118Z-debug.log
```